# How to resolve DMS failure to access LSN issue in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I am trying to use DMS to capture change logs from the SQL Server and write them to S3. I have set up a long polling period of 6 hours. (AWS recommends > 1 hour). DMS fails with the below error when the database is idle for a few hours during the night.

DMS Error:

> Last Error AlwaysOn BACKUP-ed data is not available Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0

> Error from cloud watch - Failed to access LSN '000033fc:00005314:01e6' in the backup log sets since BACKUP/LOG-s are not available

I am currently using DMS version 3.4.6 with multi-az.

I always thought the DMS reads the change data immediately after updating the T log with the DML changes. Why do we see this error even with a long polling period? Can someone explain why this issue is caused? how we can handle this?

Comment: From my understanding, DMS can read from either the active log or from log backup files. Looking at backup history, what log backup includes the LSN that it's complaining about? And when was that backup taken with respect to when the DMS job ran?

Comment: RDS SQL server backs up every 5 minutes. But long polling (6 hours) period set on MSSQL Server CDC capture job should provide DMS with enough time to parse through TLOG as it prevents TLOG from being truncated.

Comment: I'm not sure that's how they implemented it. That is, they gave DMS the ability to read from log backup files for a reason and it seems likely that reason is "so that records don't need to stay in the active log". My suspicion is that the records are removed from the active log once the log backup happens and that what you're experiencing is that the log backup that has the LSN you need is no longer available to DMS.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there any setting I could use to retain backups for longer period?

Comment: According to [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/backup-recovery/RDS.html), they get uploaded to S3. From there, I'd speculate that there's a lifecycle policy on the bucket. Now, whether you have access to a) the bucket itself and b) the lifecycle policy I don't know. But that's where I'd start!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with DMS, from my experience, we are seeing this when maintenance is running from DMS but it does not occur every time maintenance is running, the workaround for this:

- Check when the next DMS maintenance will be executed
- Stop DMS Task Associated with the DMS Instance
- Check when the DMS instance is up and running (normally takes 30min)
- Resume the DMS Task Associated with the DMS Instance

Also, follow these AWS guidelines for a proper configuration with SQL Server as a source for DMS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html

We implemented the Multi-AZ for DMS and for now, it is working with no issues at all, but it doubles our billing having another machine to cover a possible issue with DMS.